# xcrun command to export ipa file xcode8 for iphoneos10.0

Tags: ipa, xcodebuild, xcrun

```
xcrun xcodebuild -log -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "$OUTPUTDIR/$APPNAME.app" -o "$OUTPUTDIR/$APPNAME.ipa" -sign "$DEVELOPER_NAME" -embed "$PROVISIONING_PROFILE"
```

This is the command now i am using in xcode7.3.1. i updated xcode to 8.0 version. while running this command in terminal I am getting error as "warning: PackageApplication is deprecated, use `xcodebuild -exportArchive` instead."

is there any alternative command???

Answer (score 14):

In Xcode8, `xcrun PackageApplication` is deprecated, so I was successful with the use of this way.

```
#archive
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos10.0 -project Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj \
-scheme Unity-iPhone \
-configuration Release build \
-archivePath $ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY'/'$APP_NAME'.xcarchive' \
archive

#export ipa
xcodebuild -exportArchive \
-archivePath $ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY'/'$APP_NAME'.xcarchive' \
-exportPath $OUT_PATH'/' \
-exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

And the contents of `exportOptions.plist` is (for adhoc),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>YOUR_TEAM_ID</string>
    <key>uploadBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: How did you find out what could be the contents of exportOptions.plist ? I have seen dozens of samples on the web and instruction for Xcode GUI from Apple, but as usual not a single place where to refer to if I want to build my own export plist suitable for my goals ;) Thanks.

Comment: Okay, finally I was able to read the instructions in `xcodebuild -help`, but now I don't get how it decides which Provisioning Profile to use for AdHoc export. I will file a new question on SO to see if someone is aware of this.

Comment: NOTE: `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">` should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Great answer, still working for me in XCode 11.  NOTE: I have found the easiest way to get a working exportOptions.plist file is to export an archive manually from  XCode using the desired options, then copy the generated ExportOptions.plist file from the export output directory.